# Восстановление файла css

Tags: css, восстановление

Решил переписать файл css на less, скопировал не весь код и он его в него же скомпилировал, естественно старый код затерся. Есть ли возможность восстановить старый файл? Редактор кода Brackets.

Comment: Не очень понятно. Там отмены нет что ли в редакторе? css можно взять из кеша браузера, где сайт открывался но не обновляли еще через f5

Comment: Отмена то есть, но я могу только в less файле откатить и он просто будет пустой естественно css файл тоже(

Comment: Шёл 2017 год, люди до сих пор не делали бэкапы...

Comment: @andreymal или банально не использовали svn

Comment: Согласен с тем, что копирование данных всегда лишним не будет

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы подобных ситуаций не возникало используйте какую-нибудь систему контроля версиями, например Git или делайте резервные копии разработок перед какими-либо изменениями.